# Removing a node(singly linked list) by index but free(temp) is causing an endless printing of nodes

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, linked-list, free, singly-linked-list

I can't put the whole C++ program here because it is too big but here is my remove by index function:

```cpp
void remove(int index) {
    if (first_node == NULL) {
        cout << "linked list is empty !" << endl;
        throw EMPTY_LIST;
        return;
    }

    if (index < 0 || index >= count) {
        cout << "Unfortunately index is out of bound !" << endl;
        throw INDEX_OUT_OF_BOUND;
        return;
    }
    linkedNode<T> *temp = first_node;
    for (int i = 0; i < index - 1; i++)
        temp = temp->get_next();

    temp->set_next(temp->get_next()->get_next());
    // free(temp);
    this->count--;
}
```

The problem with this function is that even though it deletes any node I want successfully, when I use the `free(temp)` function and compile it makes the program print nodes infinitely. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you allocate a new node? Are you mixing `malloc/free` and `new/delete`? You shouldn't mix allocating with `new` and deallocate with `free` and vice versa.

Comment: `remove` doesn't remove the node pointed to by `temp` from the list - it removes the node pointed to by `temp->get_next()` from the list. There still exists some node `prev` for which `prev->get_next() == temp`. Then you destroy `temp`, and `prev` ends up holding a dangling pointer. Subsequent operations on the list thus corrupted are likely to exhibit undefined behavior.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you for the explanation, since it is a singly linked list and I only have a ```*next``` pointer and not a ```*previous``` pointer how can I fix the problem?

Comment: @Casey To create a new node in my program I am doing the following: 
         ```linkedNode<T> *node = new linkedNode<T>()``` so I am using ```new``` but still ```delete``` does the same problem.

Comment: Linked lists shouldn't be indexed. Including `operator[]` has implications about the underlying structure, namely that it's contiguous, which linked lists can't meet.

Comment: @sweenish I didn't know about that, thank you for the information but the assignment that I am doing is asking me to remove a node by index so I have no other choice.

Comment: At the end of the loop you are setting `temp = node[index]`, then you link `node[index+2]` to it as its next node, so basically you are jumping over `node[index+1]` not considering it. You commented the line where you delete `temp = node[index]`. It is `node[index-1]` that should get the link to `node[index+1]`. You need to have separate loops where you assign a `temp1 = node[index-1]`, another a `temp2 = node[index+1]`; you link these two; afterwards you want to delete `node[index]`.